# What is a @mask parameter in SQL Server MDS's mdq.RegexReplace() function?

Tags: sql-server, regex, master-data-services

I can't seem to find a reasonable documentation for this function definition, including its parameters. What is the range of values @mask takes and how do they influence the output?
Any help?

Comment: Here's the documenation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633843(SQL.105).aspx , and here's an explanation of the mask options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633879(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Riv: thanks. this is exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept as a solution.